# PHP Strict Standards: Declaration of should be compatible

Tags: php, extend

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

```
class O_Base {...}

class O extends O_Base {...}

abstract class A_Abstract {
    public function save(O_Base $obj) {...}
}

class A extends A_Abstract {
    public function save(O $obj) {
        echo 'save!';
    }
}

$o = new O;
$a = new A;

$a->save($o);
```

When I run this code I get the message:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of A::save() should be compatible with
>   A_Abstract::save(O_Base $obj) in .php on line 21

I know about **E_STRICT** error level but I can't find (and understand) the reason of that behavior. Can anybody help me?

Comment: In PHP, when you have `class Foo extends Bar`, the methods in `Foo` which override `Bar` methods must have same footprint. The exception is `__construct()`, which can have different footprint.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is a clear violation of [the Liskov Substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The abstract class requires an instance of `O_Base` to be passed to the `save` method, therefore *all* of the children of the `A_Abstract` should be defined in such a way that they can accept *all* instances of `O_Base`. Your child class implements a version of `save` that further restricts the API. [see another example here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218217/liskov-principle-violation-by-type-hinting)

In your code, `A` breaches the contract which `Abstract_A` enforces/describes. Just like in real life, if you sign a contract, you have to agree on certain terms, and all be in agreement over the terminology you're going to use. That's why most contracts start by naming the parties, and then saying something along the lines of *"Henceforth Mr X will be referred to as the employee"*.
These terms, like your abstract type hints are *non-negociable*, so that, further down the line you can't say: *"Oh, well... what you call expenses, I call standard wages"*
Ok, I'll stop using these half-arsed analogies, and just use a simple example to illustrate *why* what you're doing is, rightfully, not allowed.

Consider this:

```
abstract class Foo
{
    abstract public function save(Guaranteed $obj);
    //or worse still:
    final public function doStuff(Guaranteed $obj)
    {
        $obj->setSomething('to string');
        return $this->save($obj);//<====!!!!
    }
}

class FBar extends Foo
{
    public function save(Guaranteed $obj)
    {
        return $obj->setFine(true);
    }
}

class FBar2 extends Foo
{
    public function save(ChildOfGuaranteed $obj)
    {//FAIL: This method is required by Foo::doStuff to accept ALL instances of Guaranteed
    }
}
```

See here, in this case the perfectly valid abstract class is calling the `save` method with an instance of `Guaranteed`. If you were allowed to enforce a stricter type-hint in the children of this class, you could *easily* break this `doStuff` method. To help you protect yourself against these kinds of self-inflicted wounds, child classes should not be allowed to enforce stricter types on methods they inherit from their parent classes.
Also consider the scenario where we're looping over some instances and checking if they have this `save` method, based on these instances being an `instanceof Foo`:

```
$arg = new OtherChildOfGuaranteed;
$array = array(
    'fb'  => new FBar,
    'fb2' => new FBar2
);
foreach($array as $k => $class)
{
    if ($class instanceof Foo) $class->save($arg);
}
```

Now this will work fine if you just hint at `Guaranteed` in the method signature. But in the second case, we've made the type-hint a little too strict, and this code will result in a fatal error. Have fun debugging this in a more complex project...

PHP is very forgiving, if not too forgiving in most cases, but not here. Instead of having you scratching your head 'till your hear falls out, PHP very sensibly gives you a heads up, saying the implementation of your method breaches the contract, so you ***must*** fix this issue.

Now the quick workaround (and it is one in common use, too) would be this:

```
class FBar2 extends Foo
{
    /**
     * FBar2 save implementation requires instance of ChildOfGuaranteed
     *  Signature enforced by Foo
     * @return Fbar2
     * @throw InvalidArgumentException
     **/
    public function save(Guaranteed $obj)
    {
        if (!$obj instanceof ChildOfGuaranteed)
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(__METHOD__.' Expects instance of ChildOfGuaranteed, you passed '.get_class($obj));
        //do save here...
    }
}
```

So, you just leave the abstract type-hint *as-is*, but ***use the docblocks to document your code***

Comment: @tereško: the error the OP is getting has _everything_ to do with covariance: the type-hint in the child class is breaking the contract, it's breaking the liskov principle.

Comment: I agree with @EliasVanOotegem, I didn't know about such a principle, and after starting to research about the concept, I find that such error message (which I also got), can be an indicator of a design problem, lying precisely in the violation of such a wonderful principle, which helps organize a better code, avoiding future programming errors in the code you design and write yourself.

Comment: Great answer. Particularly the final code-block where you demonstrated how the parameter type is enforced in a different way. 

In a sense this rule seems TOO strict. It seems reasonable & common that a child class may need to receive a stricter, or even extra parameter given that it is a more specific instantiation of the parent class. This rule potentially forces the parent class to have parameters that are never used/relevant to it. But I can see from your example how it may be interpreted as necessary.

Comment: @Manachi: It's not too strict at all. You can add optional arguments in a child class' method. But the main reason why this is not too strict is that you can do this: `if ($o instanceof Parent) { $class = get_class($o); $new = new $class();}` where you create the new instance, all you know is that `$o` is an instance of `Parent`, so you _should_ be safe to assume that the constructors match, and all methods of `Parent` are present, and callable as defined by `Parent`, if you can change the methods, that is no longer possible

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the difference of the function signatures?

```
// A_Abstract
public function save(O_Base $obj) {...}

// A
public function save(O $obj) {
```

They are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Change A_Abstract to

```
abstract class A_Abstract {
    public function save(O $obj) {...}
}
```

No matter that `O` is extended from `O_Base`, they are two different objects, and as `A` extends `A_Abstract` the save functions need to be compatible with each other, meaning you need to pass the **same** object in, `O`.

Comment: Wrong, `O` is an instance of `O_Base`, they are compatible, though not for type hints. Change the signature in the child class to `public function save(O_Base $obj)` and it'll all work. Liskov principle

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Whilst `O` is and instance of `O_Base`, they **are** two different objects, which is why they don't work in typehints.

Comment: No, they don't work because `class A` breaches the contract, enforced by `Abstract_A`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. `O` is not `O_Base` and so breaks the rule enforced by `Abstract_A`... Why are you saying no and then arguing the same thing?

Comment: We're not saying the same thing. `O` _is an accepted argument by the rules defined by `Abstract_A`_, because `O` is a child of `O_Base`, and therefore `O instanceof O_Base` is true. The problem is the `class A`, which ignores the abstract rules, and defines another type-hint. The problem isn't the `O` class, it's the `A` class that is breaking the contract. `public function save(O_Base $obj){}` ***will*** accept an instance of `O`, because it inherits from `O` and thus _is of the same type_

Comment: Right, OK, I get you. It's the difference of allowing `O` and any other classes that extend `O_Base` and only allowing `O`. I was assuming the user only wanted `O` to be allowed in, not any other classes that extended `O_Base`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

For me the explanation is much simpler, without cool theories: in PHP the above code is making method **overriding**.
But the idea of such code in my case was method **overloading** which is not possible in PHP in this way.

So, to create required logic (required by **your application**) you need to use workarounds in order to make compatible method signatures (by inheriting parameters types or making some parameters optional).